# How to write a JIT library?

Tags: python, c, jit, compiler-construction

I've browsed through many JIT libraries. But I'd like to learn how to write one.

Softwire looked like nice. Though what the emitter interface should do? Can I do something better than existing libraries? How do I support inline caching?

Comment: Can you do something better than existing libraries? Sure, if you have more time and experience than the combined time and experience that have gone into the existing libraries.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you join an existing team instead of starting from scratch. The PyPy team's work on this area is very interesting and is currently under development, so may be a good place to start and seek more information, and then perhaps help.

---

http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/jit/overview.html

http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/jit/pyjitpl5.html

http://codespeak.net/svn/pypy/extradoc/talk/icooolps2009/bolz-tracing-jit-final.pdf

---

Other good readings on the PyPy blog:

http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2010/05/efficient-and-elegant-regular.html

http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2010/06/jit-for-regular-expression-matching.html

http://morepypy.blogspot.com/search/label/jit

---

This may interest you also:

http://indefinitestudies.org/2010/02/08/creating-a-toy-virtual-machine-with-pypy/